# Why do I get different errors when I use a non-existing alias in realurl? 404 with postvarsets, 500 with fixedpostvars

Tags: typo3, extbase, realurl

I have two different configurations for two different extensions.
With news I use postvarsets:

```
'postVarSets' =>
array (
  '_DEFAULT' =>
  array (
    'news' =>
    array (
      0 =>
      array (
        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
        'lookUpTable' =>
        array (
          'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
          'id_field' => 'uid',
          'alias_field' => 'title',
          'useUniqueCache' => 1,
          'useUniqueCache_conf' =>
          array (
            'strtolower' => 1,
            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

For an own extension to display categories I use fixedpostvars:

```
'fixedPostVars' =>
array (
  'category' =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'GETvar' => 'tx_myextension_plugin[mainCategory]',
      'lookUpTable' =>
      array (
        'table' => 'sys_category',
        'id_field' => 'uid',
        'alias_field' => 'title',
        'languageGetVar' => 'L',
        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
        'useUniqueCache_conf' =>
        array (
          'strtolower' => 1,
          'spaceCharacter' => '-',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

If I now use some invalid URL in news, I get a 404 (which is completely right).
If I now use some invalid category in my URL, I get a 500 error with the error message:

> Exception while property mapping at property path "": The identity property "ergeriguehrgoiekweukw" is no UID.

Why is there a difference between the two configurations and how can I get a 404 as well for the fixedpostvars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure but i think this is useful for you. add 'enable404forInvalidAlias' => 1, for getting 404 error. in fixedPostVars realURL configuration.